# objective-c iso C++ forbids declaration of X with no type

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

i'm having some weird compiler errors in objective-c:

```
 iBody.h:18: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'iObject' with no type
```

iObject.h

```
   #import "iElement.h"
   #import "CCSprite.h"
   #import "iBody.h"

   @interface iObject : iElement
   {
       iBody *body;
   }

    -(iObject*)initElement:(CGPoint)pos
          withName:(NSString*)name
            zIndex:(NSInteger)z
         withImage:(NSString*)image;

    -(void) addBody: (iBody*) body;
    -(iBody*) getBody;

 @end
```

iBody.h

```
  #import "iObject.h"
  #import "b2Body.h"

  @interface iBody : NSObject
  {
      CGPoint position;
      float angle;
      b2Body *body;
      iObject *parent;
   }

    -(iBody*) initElement: (CGPoint) pos
        withAngle: (float) angle
       withParent: (iObject*) el;

    -(void) setBody: (b2Body*)bdy;
    -(iObject*) getParent;

   @end
```

can someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix it. The implementation of the classes have .mm extension.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're in an import loop, since the headers of iBody and iObject are linking to one another. Typically in this situation I would consider the iObject to be of higher status and use the following in `iBody.h`:

```
// Replace the import to iObject.h with this:
@class iObject;

// Add the import back in iBody.mm
#import "iObject.h"
```

Now there is no import loop and only the implementation file of iBody actually links to `iObject.h`, and since no headers link to `iBody.mm` the issue is solved. Also, remember to rename the implementation files to `.mm` (Obj-C/C++) when working with Box2D, that gets me now and then :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have a circle include of header files.

See, you are including `iBody.h` in `iObject.h` and 'iObject.h' in `iBody.h`. So the compiler will see something like this:

```
@interface iBody : NSObject
{
  CGPoint position;
  float angle;
  b2Body *body;
  iObject *parent;
}

-(iBody*) initElement: (CGPoint) pos
    withAngle: (float) angle
   withParent: (iObject*) el;

-(void) setBody: (b2Body*)bdy;
-(iObject*) getParent;

@end

@interface iObject : iElement
{
    iBody *body;
}

-(iObject*)initElement:(CGPoint)pos
      withName:(NSString*)name
        zIndex:(NSInteger)z
     withImage:(NSString*)image;

-(void) addBody: (iBody*) body;
-(iBody*) getBody;

@end
```

As you can see `iBody` doesn't know about `iObject` when it is declined.

To resolve such situation you should just add string `@class iObject;` before `@interface iBody: NSObject` and remove include of `iObject.h` in `iBody.h`. But in implementation file `iBody.m` you should import `iObject.h`